# UIFTETextField 'Direction'

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am using the following code to create a UIFTETextField:

```
var text1_txt:UIFTETextField = new UIFTETextField();
        addChild (text1_txt );
```

Which results in the following error:

Parameter direction must be one of the accepted values.

I have absolutely no idea what this is about since I have not set anything.

I am using Flex 4.1 ACTIONSCRIPT, not MXML.

lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Flash Builder you can set breakpoint to the `public function set direction(value:String):void` method of `mx.core.FTETextField` and see what value passed there to throw exception.

**EDIT:**

Another idea where is the problem of your code. Am I right if your project isn't Flex project but ActionScript project (from your question it is not absolutely clear do you using `UIFTETextField` in ActionScript class or ActionScript project)? If so the problem is in styles. `UIFTETextField` relies on CSS styles in getting direction and some other parameters. And there is no way to set styles directly (by design).

There can be two possible solutions:

1. Use `mx.core.FTETextField`. It isn't depend on styles.
2. You should set styles of your component, containing `UIFTETextField`, before instantiation. Something like in the [following sample](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=143062). And do not forget to set `direction` style to `"rtl"`.

Comment: The value is 'ltr', which, according to the source code is a valid value. I just find it odd that just creating the textfield throws the error. I was hoping someone knew something about this textfield.

Comment: Hello, my project is Flex, but I've decided to use all Spark controls. thanks. lee

Answer (score 2):

If You Use Component With Width And Height Then It Can Be Rendered Easiely :(
Such As

```
                uiTxfUI=new Container;
                uiTxf=new UIFTETextField;
                uiTxf.text="Anshuman";
                uiTxfUI.width=uiTxfUI.height=100;

                uiTxfUI.addChild(uiTxf);
                anshu.addChild(uiTxf);
```